# How to Setup Master - Slave Replication in PhpMyAdmin GUI

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, database-replication

I'm trying to setup a master (Local Server) - slave (Remote Server) replication in PhpMyAdmin and I can't seem to find a reference how to setup without using the command line only in the PhpMyAdmin user interface.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can't. The MySQL server process has to be enabled and configured for replication in either case, and to modify the MySQL configuration you have to edit the configuration file `my.cnf`. This is not something phpMyAdmin can modify arbitrarily when connecting; it has to be set in MySQL from when the software first initializes.

That's why the directions show the relevant lines you have to modify in the MySQL configuration; because MySQL requires it to be done that way. Unfortunately, there's no way to graphically enable MySQL replication from the graphical interface alone.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Can you recommend me alternative possible solution to my problem? 

Right now I am writing a script to store every query when offline then execute all the stored query in the remote server when connected to the internet. I am still looking for simplier and more efficient solution.

Comment: There are a couple of tools that claim to be able to sync databases, I think MySQL Workbench does it. You might be able to export your entire database as an UPDATE statement. If there are only additions, not edits, uou could track which records were last exported and then export only new records (by date or by ID). You might be able to use the MySQL binary log (binlog) to track changes, but I believe that is not enabled by default so it would also would require some changes to the MySQL configuration file.